# Problem importing imblearn

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I am trying to do:

```
import imblearn
```

in my jupyter notebook, but when I run the cell I get the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

even if I have installed the package. I am using python 2.

What could the problem be, and how do I solve it?

Comment: what is `imblearn` for

Comment: @develarist, I want to use it for dealing with an imbalanced dataset

Comment: try imbalanced-learn https://pypi.org/project/imbalanced-learn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [pypi source package](https://pypi.org/project/imblearn/) you can see that they are most likely depracated and they advise you to use  imbalanced-learn instead.